# Get Data From Json Using Imacros

Tags: json, imacros

I want to perform data retrieval using iMacros sourced from json. While it generates json live http, how can I do the retrieval of data from the json using iMacros?

Examples json taken live from http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php

Below is an example of iMacros script without using live http json, how is implemented in my script?

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE customer.csv
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:actions-form ATTR=NAME:Name CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:actions-form ATTR=NAME:City CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:button-submit
```

Please help how to retrieve data from json live http as I explained above, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for the link provided:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET N EVAL("var json = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}'); json[0].Name;")
SET C EVAL("var json = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}'); json[json.length - 1].Country;")
PROMPT "First name: {{N}}\nLast country: {{C}}"
```

Comment: and then, where i include this link? http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php ?

Comment: Include it as the first line: `URL GOTO=http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php`

Answer (score 1):

Example with url for iMacros for Firefox:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_MYSQL.php
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET N EVAL("var json = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}'); json[0].Name;")
SET C EVAL("var json = JSON.parse('{{!EXTRACT}}'); json[json.length - 1].Country;")
PROMPT "First name: {{N}}\nLast country: {{C}}"
```

Or you can use javascript (file with *.js) in your iMacros for Firefox.